# ASP.NET problem when databinding

Tags: asp.net, loops

I'm trying to do a Loop with a databind in it but it isn't working as planned and I've no idea why.

```
Session("mysession") = "1234-5678-"

Dim delimiters As Char() = New Char() {"-"C}

Dim nodes As XmlNodeList

Dim mystring As String() = Trim(Session("mysession")).Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For x = 0 to mystring.Length - 1 

nodes = doc.SelectNodes("this/that[@number='" & mystring(x) & "']/something/blah")

Response.write(mystring(x))

repeater.DataSource = nodes
repeater.DataBind()

Next
```

I know that it is getting through the loop properly because I put the `response.write` in but it is only databinding the last entry in the string

Any ideas how I can make it databind each string rather than just the last one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using an `asp:XmlDataSource` inside a repeater and then did my Databind on the repeater `OnItemDataBound` event

Answer (score 1):

You are calling DataBind() in a loop.  Each time through it overwrites the previous binding values.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-binding with each iteration of the loop, so after the loop finishes it will be bound to the last thing you told it to bind to, which is the last iteration of the loop.

(Note: Data binding doesn't mean "append this data to the control's existing data" but rather "use this data for the control."  It's a destructive operation, replacing what was previously there.)

You should build your data source first (presumably with the loop) and then bind to the fully-built data source after the loop is completed.  Presumably this means you'll want to *append* to `nodes` with each iteration, rather than *assign* to it (which overwrites what's already there).  However, you'll want to debug a little and make sure the appended version still makes sense data-wise and can still be bound to.  It may need some delineation between loop iterations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Every `DataBind()` you do overwrite the previous ones. And same with the `DataSource`.
Move those outside of the loop, and instead of
`nodes = doc.SelectNodes("this/that[@number='" & mystring(x) & "']/something/blah")`
, append the new node to the `XmlNodeList`.

`nodes += doc.SelectNodes("this/that[@number='" & mystring(x) & "']/something/blah")`
or whatever the equivalent VB code is.

Comment: I tried this but i get an error `Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList'.` Seems like the thing I need to do but not too sure how to go about it - Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I don't know enough about Xml, but it appears that you cannot append to an XmlNodeList. So you'd have to find some way to keep a list of the XmlNodes that you can append to in the loop, then set that list as the DataSource after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you need to put your repeater into another repeater.
Something like

```
<Repeater ID="outerrepeater">
<Repeater ID="innerrepeater" />
</Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind

```
PageLoad or whatever
{
    outerrepeater.OnDataBound += new RepeaterDataBoundEvent(databind); //or is it ondatabinding
    outerrepeater.DataSource = mystring;
    outerrepeater.DataBind();
}

void databind(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater inner = ((Repeater)((Repeater)sender).FindControl("innerrepeater"));
    inner.DataSource = doc.SelectNodes("this/that[@number='" & mystring(x) & "']/something/blah");
    inner.DataBind();
}
```

Sorry it's in C# but that is the general jist of what I think you are trying to do.